# Sigma-field generated by a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I encountered the following statement where $X_1, ..., X_n$ are random variables, then
$$
\sigma(X_1, ... , X_n) = \sigma(\cup_{i=1}^n \sigma(X_i)).
$$
I managed to prove the direction where
$$
\sigma(X_1, ... , X_n) \subset \sigma(\cup_{i=1}^n \sigma(X_i)),
$$
but I have no idea where to start for the other inclusion. I encountered a solution for this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320368/if-y-1-x-1-x-l-then-sigmay-1-sigma-left-cup-i-1l-sigmax-i-ri) but I did not understand what bundled map or coordinate map are. I also did not think the proof was rigorous enough. Can anyone provide something more concrete and easy to understand? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma(X_i) \subset \sigma(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ for each $i$ so $\bigcup_{1\leq i \leq n}\sigma(X_i) \subset \sigma(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$. This implies that $\sigma (\bigcup_{1\leq i \leq n}\sigma(X_i)) \subset \sigma(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ by definition of $\sigma (\bigcup_{1\leq i \leq n}\sigma(X_i))$ as the smallest sigma algebra containing $\bigcup_{1\leq i \leq n}\sigma(X_i)$.

Comment: Oh my god.. This is actually so easy. Don't know why I did not think of this. Thank you so much!